# Dynamically load another Angular app in a Angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-bootstrap, micro-frontend, angular-builder

I am currently looking for a solution in angular on how I could load a separate application into one.
Something like:

```
applicationA    
- main.js
- vendor.js
- 1.js (chunk)
```

```
applicationB
- main.js
- vendor.js
- 1.js
- 2.js
```

`applicationA` will load `applicationB` on route `/appb` and also able to do `appb/subroute`.

The ultimate goal for this is so that multiple teams can develop multiple apps separately and when something is changed in `applicationA`, all the application that is called by applicationA does not need to redeploy.

I was looking at this article and got me really close: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/building-extensible-dynamic-pluggable-enterprise-application-with-angular-aed8979faba5. However, I could not get it to run with sub route and is build on top of a set of modules, not an application.

Finally, an article from Manfred Steyer , https://www.angulararchitects.io/aktuelles/dynamic-module-federation-with-angular/, this one is what I really want, but, this is build on an "next" technology that are yet mature and not an Angular release nor in its roadmap (I think).

Question:
Has anyone have built this kind of solution that I can get some pointers from?

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Nx** by [Nrwl.io](https://nrwl.io/).
Given your use case you will greatly benefit from it.
Its relatively easy to setup and is immensely powerful and robust